# Is there a way to duplicate an action button from one Google sheets file to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, events

TL;DR: I'm looking for a way to add an action button using an existing google-script to all future-added files in a Drive folder.

Hi all,
I have a Google-apps script that checks for a change in files count in a Google Drive folder, and upon change applies a certain script to it (all the scripts are in the same project and all files are in the same format).
I've decided I want to add an action button to one of the sheets to apply a specific filter upon users' requests.

I'm looking for a way to add this action button to all of the future-added files.
I've thought of the next possible implementations:

1. Create a drawing using the script - I couldn't manage to find a method that generates a new drawing.
2. Make a specific range clickable - Also couldn't find a way to do that
3. Add a menu to the file's toolbar - I get an exception thrown that `SpreadsheetApp.newMenu()` can't be called from the current context.

Did anybody implement something similar and can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Instant Tool Bar

Here's a couple of functions that allow you to build a sidebar that provides you with instant access to a variety of html controls including buttons which can call any server side function via google.script.run.

The first function launches the sidebar which provides instant access to a variety of tools which can be created with html.

```
function launchSideBarButtons() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let html = '<html><head><style>input {margin: 2px 5px 1px 0;}</style></head><body>';
  html += '<input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="Enter Folder Id" value="folderid" />';//Change the folderid to the default folder that you wish to check on enter a new folder id at the time just prior to execution
  html += '<br><input type= "text" id="txt2" placeholder="Display Number Files" readonly />';
  html += '<br><input type="button" value="Check Folder" onClick="checkFolder();" />';
  html += '<script>';
  html += 'function checkFolder() { let id=document.getElementById("txt1").value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(l){document.getElementById("txt2").value=l;}).checkMyFolder(id);}';
  html += 'console.log("My Code")';
  html += '</script></body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle("Instant Tool Bar"));
}
```

This function is the server side function that actually opens the folder and counts the number of files.

```
function checkMyFolder(id) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  if (folder) {
    const files = folder.getFiles();
    let n = 0;
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      n++;
    }
    return n;
  } else {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Check folder id")}
}
```

This function creates a  installable onMyNewOpen() trigger that will launch the side bar when the spreadsheet opens thus making it unnecessary for you to have to go looking through a menu for a button click.  It's setup so that it will only create one trigger no matter how many times you run it.

```
function onMyNewOpen() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "launchSideBarButtons").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("launchSideBarButtons").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onOpen().create();
  }
}
```

The Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mimi! I've learned a lot by applying this.

Answer (score 0):

As for the Menu, you can try this:

```
function onOpen() { //[OPTIONAL] Created a custom menu "Timestamp" on your Spreadsheet, where you can run the script
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Whatever you want it to be called') //keep the ''
      .addItem('Function Description', 'function call') //for the function, don't use ()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('submenu name') //only if needed
        .addItem('Function Description','function call')
        .addSeparator() //aestethics only
        .addItem('Function Description','function call')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! your code did generate a new menu in the original Sheets file attached to the script. I guess the simplest solution of adding such a menu *to each new file* in the folder is to open a new copy of the script and attach it to the new file as well? (or is there a way to run `onOpen` from the script of file A on file B by its ID?)

Comment: I never actually used any script between different files, but I guess the `onOpen` will only trigger when file A opens.  You could create a script to copy it to File B, but maybe it's less trouble to just open it and copy-paste the code there.